# Adding Icons to Drupal 7 print function

Tags: drupal, printing

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $rows[] = array(
    $i,
    $row->country_name,
    $status = ($row->status == 0) ? 'Inactive' : 'Active',
    date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($row->added_date)),
    l('Edit', 'mypages/countries/'. $row->id), 
    l('Delete', 'mypages/delete/'. $row->country_name)
  );
  $i++;
}
```

In the above function there is **edit and delete** links there i need to add related fa icons to those two `edit and delete` ... 
I have tried by adding like this below

```
l('<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit', 'mypages/countries/'. $row->id), 
l('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete', 'mypages/delete/'. $row->country_name)
```

As per above the icons not working is there any other way to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `l()` function will escape all HTML by default. You need to pass third argument that lets HTML be included. Here is the correct code:

```
l('<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit', 'mypages/countries/'. $row->id, array('html' => TRUE)), 
l('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete', 'mypages/delete/'. $row->country_name, array('html' => TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi...can you check with below question as well in drupal 7 .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649414/how-to-make-drupal-7-editable-field-in-table-for-admin-only